# storing the python-dictionary with 10000 lines in mysql - instead of printing

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql, database

see below 
**update 2** i did as you adviced me:

**update:** see the important updates:

want to store the data to the mysql-db

```
{'url': 'http://dom1', 'name': 'miller', 'name2': 'phil man', 'email-adress': 'waddehadde@hotmail.com'}
{'url': 'http://dom2', 'name': 'jonboy', 'name2': 'Josef dude', 'email-adress': 'waddehadde@hotmail.com'}
```

I have a very simple dataset  but it s quite very big: approx 10 k records. 
i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python And i found out that i probably can use peewee

```
import peewee
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase('jonhydb', user='john',passwd='megajonhy')

class Book(peewee.Model):
    author = peewee.CharField()
    title = peewee.TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

Book.create_table()
book = Book(author="me", title='Peewee is cool')
book.save()
for book in Book.filter(author="me"):
    print book.title

Peewee is cool
```

I know of two ways to do this, one being storing the number in a file on the server
the otehr is to serve it in a database, using MySQL to store this. i can use PHP - to store it in the mysql-db. simple, right? But yesterday ive  found out that Python is even better.  I have installed python on my linux-distri

but it seem overcomplicated to me.

So this takes me to a question, is there a way to store a this dataset with using MySQL and python peewee or some simliar leightweight orm!?

first of all - many many thanks for the quick answer

i am on opensuse verision 13.1 
the mysql db is allready up and running.

well first of all  i had to install peewee and json 
while i had some isseus installing peewee - see  below 
i afterwards tried to install simplejson - as a replacement for json 
then i guess that peewee was installabe. - see below:

had issues with installing peewee

```
martin@linux-70ce:~>
martin@linux-70ce:~> git clone https://github.com/coleifer/peewee.git
Klone nach 'peewee'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 5673, done.
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 5686 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Empfange Objekte: 100% (5686/5686), 3.54 MiB | 102.00 KiB/s, done.
Löse Unterschiede auf: 100% (3468/3468), done.
Prüfe Konnektivität... Fertig
martin@linux-70ce:~> cd peewee
martin@linux-70ce:~/peewee> python setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-5717.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:
Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
martin@linux-70ce:~/peewee>
```

afer that - as written above - i installed simplejson and then i tried to install peewee again :: now i guess i had more luck....

```
martin@linux-70ce:~/peewee> git clone https://github.com/coleifer/peewee.git
Klone nach 'peewee'...                                                                                                                                                             
remote: Reusing existing pack: 5673, done.
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 5686 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Empfange Objekte: 100% (5686/5686), 3.54 MiB | 309.00 KiB/s, done.                                                                                                                 
fix the conflicts: 100% (3468/3468), done.
```

Prüfe Konnektivität... Fertig
martin@linux-70ce:~/peewee>

SEE THE FULL CODE - THAT I AM RUNNING

```
import urllib
import urlparse
import re
from peewee import *
import json

db = MySQLDatabase('cpan', user='root',passwd='rimbaud')

class User(Model):
    name = TextField()
    cname = TextField()
    email = TextField()
    url = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the cpan database


User.create_table() #ensure table is created


url = "http://search.cpan.org/author/?W"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
for lk, capname, name in re.findall('<a href="(/~.*?/)"><b>(.*?)</b></a><br/><small>(.*?)</small>', html):

    alk = urlparse.urljoin(url, lk)

    data = { 'url':alk, 'name':name, 'cname':capname }

    phtml = urllib.urlopen(alk).read()
    memail = re.search('<a href="mailto:(.*?)">', phtml)
    if memail:
        data['email'] = memail.group(1)


data = json.load() #your json data file here

for entry in data: #assuming your data is an array of JSON objects
    user = User.create(name=entry["name"], cname=entry["cname"],
        email=entry["email"], url=entry["url"])
    user.save()
```

and the subsequently results:

```
       martin@linux-70ce:~/perl> python cpan6.py
python: can't open file 'cpan6.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
martin@linux-70ce:~/perl> python cpan5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cpan5.py", line 7, in <module>
    from peewee import *
ImportError: No module named peewee
martin@linux-70ce:~/perl>
```

well at the moment i am a bit clueless - love to hear from you
many thanks in advance!!

**update 2** i did as you adviced me:

```
martin@linux-70ce:~/peewee> sudo python setup.py install 

t
linux-70ce:/home/martin/perl # cd ..
linux-70ce:/home/martin # cd peewee/
linux-70ce:/home/martin/peewee #  sudo python setup.py install 
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating peewee.egg-info
writing peewee.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to peewee.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to peewee.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'peewee.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'peewee.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'peewee.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
copying peewee.py -> build/lib
copying pwiz.py -> build/lib
creating build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_shortcuts.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/read_slave.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_kv.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_pwiz.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/gfk.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/test_utils.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/apsw_ext.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/__init__.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_pool.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_apsw.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/kv.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/postgres_ext.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/signals.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/sqlcipher_ext.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_gfk.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_read_slave.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/pool.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_csv_loader.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_berkeleydb.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/djpeewee.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_test_utils.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/migrate.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/csv_loader.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_postgres.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_migrate.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_djpeewee.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_sqlite_ext.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/berkeleydb.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/proxy.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_signals.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/sqlite_ext.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/tests_sqlcipher_ext.py -> build/lib/playhouse
copying playhouse/shortcuts.py -> build/lib/playhouse
creating build/bdist.linux-i686
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
copying build/lib/peewee.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_shortcuts.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/read_slave.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_kv.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_pwiz.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/gfk.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/test_utils.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/apsw_ext.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_pool.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_apsw.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/kv.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/postgres_ext.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/signals.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/sqlcipher_ext.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_gfk.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_read_slave.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/pool.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_csv_loader.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_berkeleydb.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/djpeewee.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_test_utils.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/migrate.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/csv_loader.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_postgres.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_migrate.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_djpeewee.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_sqlite_ext.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/berkeleydb.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/proxy.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_signals.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/sqlite_ext.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/tests_sqlcipher_ext.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/playhouse/shortcuts.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse
copying build/lib/pwiz.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/peewee.py to peewee.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_shortcuts.py to tests_shortcuts.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/read_slave.py to read_slave.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_kv.py to tests_kv.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_pwiz.py to tests_pwiz.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/gfk.py to gfk.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/test_utils.py to test_utils.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/apsw_ext.py to apsw_ext.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_pool.py to tests_pool.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_apsw.py to tests_apsw.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/kv.py to kv.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/postgres_ext.py to postgres_ext.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/signals.py to signals.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/sqlcipher_ext.py to sqlcipher_ext.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_gfk.py to tests_gfk.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_read_slave.py to tests_read_slave.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/pool.py to pool.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_csv_loader.py to tests_csv_loader.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_berkeleydb.py to tests_berkeleydb.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/djpeewee.py to djpeewee.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_test_utils.py to tests_test_utils.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/migrate.py to migrate.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/csv_loader.py to csv_loader.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_postgres.py to tests_postgres.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_migrate.py to tests_migrate.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_djpeewee.py to tests_djpeewee.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_sqlite_ext.py to tests_sqlite_ext.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/berkeleydb.py to berkeleydb.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/proxy.py to proxy.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_signals.py to tests_signals.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/sqlite_ext.py to sqlite_ext.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/tests_sqlcipher_ext.py to tests_sqlcipher_ext.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/playhouse/shortcuts.py to shortcuts.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pwiz.py to pwiz.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
installing scripts to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO/scripts
running install_scripts
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting pwiz.py -> build/scripts-2.7
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pwiz.py from 644 to 755
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO/scripts
copying build/scripts-2.7/pwiz.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO/scripts
changing mode of build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/pwiz.py to 755
copying peewee.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying peewee.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying peewee.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying peewee.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/peewee-2.2.5-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing peewee-2.2.5-py2.7.egg
Copying peewee-2.2.5-py2.7.egg to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding peewee 2.2.5 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pwiz.py script to /usr/bin

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/peewee-2.2.5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for peewee==2.2.5
Finished processing dependencies for peewee==2.2.5
linux-70ce:/home/martin/peewee #
```

see the latest update - after insalling peewee correctly i runned the script and now see what happened.

```
import urllib
import urlparse
import re
import peewee
import json

db = MySQLDatabase('cpan', user='root',passwd='rimbaud')

class User(Model):
    name = TextField()
    cname = TextField()
    email = TextField()
    url = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the cpan database


User.create_table() #ensure table is created


url = "http://search.cpan.org/author/?W"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
for lk, capname, name in re.findall('<a href="(/~.*?/)"><b>(.*?)</b></a><br/><small>(.*?)</small>', html):
    alk = urlparse.urljoin(url, lk)

    data = { 'url':alk, 'name':name, 'cname':capname }

    phtml = urllib.urlopen(alk).read()
    memail = re.search('<a href="mailto:(.*?)">', phtml)
    if memail:
        data['email'] = memail.group(1)


data = json.load() #your json data file here

for entry in data: #assuming your data is an array of JSON objects
    user = User.create(name=entry["name"], cname=entry["cname"],
        email=entry["email"], url=entry["url"])
    user.save()
```

i got back this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cpan5.py", line 10, in <module>
    db = MySQLDatabase('cpan', user='root',passwd='rimbaud')
NameError: name 'MySQLDatabase' is not defined
linux-70ce:/home/martin/perl #
```

**the newest update:**  from july 14th

assuming this is all right now - i have set up this... so 
well - but it fails at a certain point.

```
import urllib
import urlparse
import re
# import peewee
import json
from peewee import *



#from peewee import MySQLDatabase ('cpan', user='root',passwd='rimbaud') 


db = MySQLDatabase('cpan', user='root',passwd='rimbaud') 

class User(Model):
    name = TextField()
    cname = TextField()
    email = TextField()
    url = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the cpan database


User.create_table() #ensure table is created


url = "http://search.cpan.org/author/?W"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
for lk, capname, name in re.findall('<a href="(/~.*?/)"><b>(.*?)</b></a><br/><small>(.*?)</small>', html):
    alk = urlparse.urljoin(url, lk)

    data = { 'url':alk, 'name':name, 'cname':capname }

    phtml = urllib.urlopen(alk).read()
    memail = re.search('<a href="mailto:(.*?)">', phtml)
    if memail:
        data['email'] = memail.group(1)


data = json.load('email') #your json data file here

for entry in data: #assuming your data is an array of JSON objects
    user = User.create(name=entry["name"], cname=entry["cname"],
        email=entry["email"], url=entry["url"])
    user.save()
```

guess that there a data-file must exist: one that have been created by the script during the parsing... is this right?

```
)
martin@linux-70ce:~/perl> python cpan_100.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cpan_100.py", line 47, in <module>
    data = json.load('email') #your json data file here
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
martin@linux-70ce:~/perl>
```

love to hear from you

Comment: When running your python setup scripts for peewee and simplejson you must use sudo. As above: `martin@linux-70ce:~/peewee> sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: `import peewee` will pull the entire module in and keep the namespace, so you would have to do things like peewee.Model, etc. Use of `from x import *` is discouraged, but for small scripts and examples it is a convienence. This allows for all classes and methods of the module to be accessed directly. In your case the `import peewee` line has no effect and could be removed.

Comment: i did two updates -. see  the newest **update 2** i did as you adviced me: and installed it as su - now i am going to try out all. i come back and report all the findings

Comment: please see the newest update - the third update...- where i have documented the new run of the scirpt. guess that i have some issues with the name of the db. love to hear from you

Comment: Your error is due to MySQLDatabase not being in the root scope. You must import it explicitly `from peewee import MySQLDatabase`, import everything `from peewee import *` or reference it on the peewee scope `peewee.MySQLDatabase`.

Comment: hello dear bob - many many thanks  well i am pretty new to the python and peewee-things. i have issues in the load file..... line somewhat 47, i would love to hear from you

Comment: It looks like you are already populating the `data` object when parsing the html, so you can omit the `data = json.load('email')` line and simply access your `data` object directly in the for loop at the end as written. I added that line as an example as I did not know where you were getting your data from initially.

Comment: You also might want to do `data = []` before your html parsing loop and then do `entry = { 'url':alk, 'name':name, 'cname':capname }` and `data.append(entry.copy())` within the loop.

Comment: at the moment it does not work ... no glue why

Comment: can you please add the full code - eg in the answer below. that would be great and would help alot . thanks in advance-

Comment: Why mix php and Python pick one and stick with it, both are good but don't confuse your self with the 2 for the same system

Comment: Martin - many thanks for the reply - you comment is very helpful. i ve got stuck. i need a solution that workds. And i guess that i am a bit confused. Can you vie me some helping hand. i would be more than happy - love to hear from you - greetings martin aka user 37xx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to use python and peewee, I would do something like the following:

```
from peewee import *
import json

db = MySQLDatabase('jonhydb', user='john',passwd='megajonhy')

class User(Model):
    name = TextField()
    name2 = TextField()
    email_address = TextField()
    url = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the jonhydb database

User.create_table() #ensure table is created

data = json.load() #your json data file here

for entry in data: #assuming your data is an array of JSON objects
    user = User.create(name=entry["name"], name2=entry["name2"],
        email_address=entry["email-adress"], url=entry["url"])
    user.save()
```

Comment: many thanks  . well i have had some issues. plz see above. 
well at the moment i am a bit clueless - love to hear from you
many thanks in advance!!      love to hear from you

Comment: i did two updates -. see  the newest **update 2** i did as you adviced me: and installed it as su

Comment: well i runned into troubles... can anybody help out here

Comment: hello  - at the moment the script does not work - can you help - thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
#write format that way:-

import peewee
import MySQLdb

con = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="admin")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS erp_master')

db = peewee.MySQLDatabase('erp_master', user='root',passwd='admin')

class Bank(peewee.Model):
    bank_id     = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    bank_name   = peewee.CharField()
    Account_no  = peewee.IntegerField()
    ifc_code    = peewee.IntegerField()
    swift_code  = peewee.IntegerField(null = True)

    class Meta:
        database = db
db.create_tables([Bank], safe=True)

#it works perfect without any error
```